# Crosstab query generates Run-Time error '13' Type mismatch

Tags: ms-access, vba

Trying to create cross tab reports in datasheets.  I have a long setup query that filters whats needed for the reports. I have a button on a form for each report. Here is the code, in the on_click event of a button, that has the type mismatch:

```
Dim SKbyYrByMo As String
SKbyYrByMo = "TRANSFORM Sum([1ACTMasterQuery].Extension) AS SumOfExtension" 
& _
SKbyYrByMo = SKbyYrByMo + " SELECT [1ACTMasterQuery].Year, 
[1ACTMasterQuery].Sku, Sum([1ACTMasterQuery].Extension) AS [Total Of 
Extension]" & _
SKbyYrByMo = SKbyYrByMo + " FROM 1ACTMasterQuery" & _
SKbyYrByMo = SKbyYrByMo + " GROUP BY [1ACTMasterQuery].Year, 
[1ACTMasterQuery].Sku" & _
SKbyYrByMo = SKbyYrByMo + " PIVOT [1ACTMasterQuery].MonthNo"

DoCmd.RunSQL SKbyYrByMo
```

The setup query has dates, and I was wondering if that is a problem when setting up SQL in a string.  The query runs fine if run via DoCmd.OpenQuery "1ACTMasterQuery" where 1ACTMasterQuery is in  the ACCESS query list.  But I need to run it in vba.  Let me know if more informationion is needed.

Thanks

jpl458

Answer (score 0):

You string syntax is flawed. Try:

```
SKbyYrByMo = "TRANSFORM Sum([1ACTMasterQuery].Extension) AS SumOfExtension" & _
" SELECT [1ACTMasterQuery].Year, [1ACTMasterQuery].Sku, Sum([1ACTMasterQuery].Extension) AS [Total Of Extension]" & _
" FROM 1ACTMasterQuery" & _
" GROUP BY [1ACTMasterQuery].Year, [1ACTMasterQuery].Sku" & _
" PIVOT [1ACTMasterQuery].MonthNo"
```

Comment: You might also note that you can't `DoCmd.RunSQL` a non-action query.

Comment: Thanks @ErikvonAsmuth ... didn't get that far.

Comment: I copied your code and it gave me the following error at this command. DoCmd.RunSQL SKbyTrByMo. Runtime error 2342 ARunSQL action requires an argument consisting of an SQL Statement

Comment: RunSQL only work for Action Queries, I just read. The query above will return data and display in a datasheet when run in ACCESS.  How do I get the same result in VBA? Do I have to create a record set? Then how do I get the data into a datasheet.

Comment: Use it as _RecordSource_ for your datasheet/form.